# Rotation for stiffness tensor does not match reference

Tags: tensor-calculus, rotation

**TLDR**: I want to rotate a stiffness tensor in Voigt notation, but my rotation matrix does not match a reference solution. The values are the same but some signs are reversed. I don't see what I am overlooking. Any help is appreciated!

**In detail**: I start with a basic rotation matrix
$$
    Q_{x} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
    0 & \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, according to [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/35602/37412) or [this online book](http://solidmechanics.org/Text/Chapter3_2/Chapter3_2.php) or [5] the rotation matrix for a stiffness tensor in Voigt notation should be
$$
        K = \begin{bmatrix}Q_{11}^{2} & Q_{12}^{2} & Q_{13}^{2} &
        2 Q_{12} Q_{13} & 2 Q_{11} Q_{13} & 2 Q_{11} Q_{12}\\
        Q_{21}^{2} & Q_{22}^{2} & Q_{23}^{2} & 2 Q_{22} Q_{23} &
        2 Q_{21} Q_{23} & 2 Q_{21} Q_{22}\\
        Q_{31}^{2} & Q_{32}^{2} & Q_{33}^{2} & 2 Q_{32} Q_{33} &
        2 Q_{31} Q_{33} & 2 Q_{31} Q_{32}\\
        Q_{21} Q_{31} & Q_{22} Q_{32} & Q_{23} Q_{33} & Q_{22}
        Q_{33} + Q_{23} Q_{32} & Q_{21} Q_{33} + Q_{23} Q_{31}
        & Q_{21} Q_{32} + Q_{22} Q_{31}\\
        Q_{11} Q_{31} & Q_{12} Q_{32} & Q_{13} Q_{33} & Q_{12}
        Q_{33} + Q_{13} Q_{32} & Q_{11} Q_{33} + Q_{13} Q_{31}
        & Q_{11} Q_{32} + Q_{12} Q_{31}\\
        Q_{11} Q_{21} & Q_{12} Q_{22} & Q_{13} Q_{23} & Q_{12}
        Q_{23} + Q_{13} Q_{22} & Q_{11} Q_{23} + Q_{13} Q_{21}
        & Q_{11} Q_{22} + Q_{12} Q_{21}\end{bmatrix}
$$

Reference solutions for $Q_x$ are given [in the same online book](http://solidmechanics.org/Text/Chapter3_2/Chapter3_2.php) or [here](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S1758825116500769) with $\cos(\theta)=c\,$ and $\,\sin(\theta)=s$
$$
K_{\mathrm{ref}} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c^2 & s^2 & 2sc & 0 & 0\\
0 & s^2 & c^2 & -2sc & 0 & 0\\
0 & -sc & sc & c^2-s^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0& 0& 0& c & -s \\
0& 0& 0& 0& s & c 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The following entries don't match:
$$
\begin{align}
K_{24}=&2Q_{22}Q_{23}=2c(-s) &\neq 2sc\\
K_{34}=&2Q_{32}Q_{33}=2sc &\neq -2sc\\
K_{42}=&Q_{22}Q_{32}=cs &\neq -sc\\
K_{43}=&Q_{23}Q_{33}=-sc &\neq sc\\
K_{56}=&Q_{11}Q_{32}+Q_{12}Q_{31}=s &\neq -s\\
K_{65}=&Q_{11}Q_{23}+Q_{13}Q_{21}=-s &\neq s
\end{align}
$$

So the signs are reversed, but I don't see what I am overlooking.

**More detail**: I did the same but for Kelvin's notation. Here in [6] the matrix $K_{\mathrm{Kel}}$ is given as
$$
K_{\mathrm{kel}} = \begin{bmatrix}Q_{11}^{2} & Q_{12}^{2} & Q_{13}^{2} &
        \sqrt{2} Q_{12} Q_{13} & \sqrt{2} Q_{11} Q_{13} & \sqrt{2} Q_{11} Q_{12}\\
        Q_{21}^{2} & Q_{22}^{2} & Q_{23}^{2} & \sqrt{2} Q_{22} Q_{23} &
        \sqrt{2} Q_{21} Q_{23} & \sqrt{2} Q_{21} Q_{22}\\
        Q_{31}^{2} & Q_{32}^{2} & Q_{33}^{2} & \sqrt{2} Q_{32} Q_{33} &
        \sqrt{2} Q_{31} Q_{33} & \sqrt{2} Q_{31} Q_{32}\\
        \sqrt{2}Q_{21} Q_{31} & \sqrt{2}Q_{22} Q_{32} & \sqrt{2}Q_{23} Q_{33} & Q_{22}
        Q_{33} + Q_{23} Q_{32} & Q_{21} Q_{33} + Q_{23} Q_{31}
        & Q_{21} Q_{32} + Q_{22} Q_{31}\\
        \sqrt{2}Q_{11} Q_{31} & \sqrt{2}Q_{12} Q_{32} & \sqrt{2}Q_{13} Q_{33} & Q_{12}
        Q_{33} + Q_{13} Q_{32} & Q_{11} Q_{33} + Q_{13} Q_{31}
        & Q_{11} Q_{32} + Q_{12} Q_{31}\\
        \sqrt{2}Q_{11} Q_{21} & \sqrt{2}Q_{12} Q_{22} & \sqrt{2}Q_{13} Q_{23} & Q_{12}
        Q_{23} + Q_{13} Q_{22} & Q_{11} Q_{23} + Q_{13} Q_{21}
        & Q_{11} Q_{22} + Q_{12} Q_{21}\end{bmatrix}
$$

And a reference solution for a rotation about the third ($z$) axis

$$
K_{\mathrm{Kel, ref}} = \begin{bmatrix}c^2 & s^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}sc \\
s^2 & c^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2}sc\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & c & -s & 0 \\
0 & 0& 0& s& c & 0 \\
-\sqrt{2}sc& \sqrt{2}sc& 0& 0& 0 & c^2-s^2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In this case, the reference matches the $K_{\mathrm{Kel}}$ matrix, particularly the signs are correct.

[5] p.89, M. A. Slawinski, Seismic waves and rays in elastic media. Amsterdam: Pergamon, 2003.

[6] M. M. Mehrabi and S. C. COWIN, “Eigentensors of linear anisotropic elastic materials,” Q J Mechanics Appl Math, vol. 43, no. 1, pp. 15–41, 1990, doi: 10.1093/qjmam/43.1.15. [PDF](https://academic.oup.com/qjmam/article-pdf/43/1/15/5377796/43-1-15.pdf)

Comment: its because of the sign of  $\theta$. if the you change the sign of $\theta$ in $k_ref$ you get $k$

Comment: the resion for that, in that chinese paper they perform passive transformation(they rotate coordinate system) in latter I suppose they do active transformation(coordinate system is fixed but the vectors are rotated)

Comment: read this https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bo_Lan/publication/280716878_A_Brief_Guide_to_the_Fundamentals_of_Passive_and_Active_Rotations_in_Material_Science/links/55c230fa08aeb975673e3d21/A-Brief-Guide-to-the-Fundamentals-of-Passive-and-Active-Rotations-in-Material-Science.pdf

Comment: Thank you I will read the publication. 
I actually tried taking $-\theta$ instead of $\theta$ and it did not work. But when I change the sign in the corresponding entries for the reference solution I get the correct rotation.

Comment: in your case $k_{ref}$ with $\theta$ matches with $k$ with $-\theta$ but I am not sure if it is due to active versus passive, it may be due to how they define the angle so the best would be to read that active versus passive paper I send then you will understand what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up transforming back to the full (3x3x3x3) stiffness tensor, rotating it, and transforming it back to Voigt notation.

So  I used
$$ \mathbf{C}' = \mathbf{R}\cdot\mathbf{R}\cdot\mathbf{C}\cdot\mathbf{R}^{\top}\mathbf{R}^{\top} $$
which is according to [this description](http://www.continuummechanics.org/rotationmatrix.html) an (active) rotation of of a tensor while the coordinate system remains fixed.

With this, I could check that rotating a stiffness tensor in Voigt notation
$$C_{Voigt}'= KC_{Voigt}K^{\top}$$
with the transform and active rotation matrix from [the original post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591812/278988)
yields the same stiffnesses. One note on the rotation matrix, this is an activce rotation matrix if one takes original and resulting vector in the same coordinate system.

I did the transforms from tensor to Voigt notation and back with the functions found in the `elasticity.py` file of the [matscipy package](https://github.com/libAtoms/matscipy).

I furthermore checked the $K$ matrices with $K_{\mathrm{ref}}$ from [this source](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cageo.2012.05.031) who updated the original references from Allan Bower's book.

Comment: Thank you! Just as an add-on. After a bit of digging, I used the transformation matrix from the following article to get the rotations: Igor Ravve, Zvi Koren, Directional derivatives of ray velocity in anisotropic elastic media, Geophysical Journal International, Volume 216, Issue 2, February 2019, Pages 859–895, https://doi.org/10.1093/gji/ggy445 > I ended up transforming back to the full (3x3x3x3) stiffness tensor, rotating it, and transforming it back to Voigt notation. I compared with this, and I found the transformed stiffness tensor in voigt notation matching.